# How to remove vector tiles tile bounding in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, polygon, geoserver, vector-tiles, bounding

I use leaflet to load vt tiles,which data geom type is polygon.I found that when loading, this will show a line betwwen tiles.
So how to remove this bounding line?
[image: tile bounding]

[image]

Maybe this is the issue of Geoserver,Which I used to publish pbf vt.

Comment: Which the map layer are you using?

Comment: Hi，@LeKhiem. I use Leaflet 1.5.1 and Leaflet.VectorGrid to add pbf vt layer.

Comment: You can try this plugin https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.TileLayer.NoGap

Comment: Maybe not.This question caused by the polygon cutting.When cut a big polygon to 256*256 tiles,It will generated many small polygons. And when use leaflet to loading these tiles, It means to loaded many small polygon,not origin big polygon.

Comment: Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255545/dissolve-leaflet-vectorgrid-polygon-at-tile-boundary-by-id

Comment: @IvanSanchez Tanks,I had seen your reply at github,But I want to know how to do in geoserver?Can you give me some suggestion?