# Cutting polygon geometry to vector-tiles with Bounding Line

Tags: polygon, geoserver, vector-tiles

Just like what I had said at [How to remove vector tiles tile bounding in Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912496/how-to-remove-vector-tiles-tile-bounding-in-leaflet) and something had said at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/120 . But I want to know how to solve this problem. I'm using geoserver 2.15 to cut vector-tiles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove vector tiles tile bounding in Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912496/how-to-remove-vector-tiles-tile-bounding-in-leaflet)

Comment: Yes, These two questions are all questioned by me.These two questioned in two direction.

Comment: what don't you understand about the other answers?

Comment: I understand it,But I want to know how to solve this `buffer` problem in geoserver,I haven't found.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem by setting the `Default Rendering Buffer` at the layer settings.